# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and unknown targets

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2023-07-04 15:45:03.777618: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:637] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
847/847 [==============================] - 50s 58ms/step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dxw/123/SJBCD-PAP/evaluation.py", line 45, in <module>
    evaluate(test_file)
  File "/home/dxw/123/SJBCD-PAP/evaluation.py", line 34, in evaluate
    print(classification_report(test_labels, yy_pred, digits=4))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 2110, in classification_report
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 93, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and unknown targets
```

my code is

```
import time
import _pickle as cPickle
from sjbcd import builde_model, read_file
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report





def evaluate(test_file):
    max_opcodes_length = 300
    tokenizer_save_path = 'SJBCD-PAP/something_files/tokenizer-bcb.pkl'

    test_opcodes1, test_opcodes2, test_labels = read_file(test_file)
    tokenizer = cPickle.load(open(tokenizer_save_path, 'rb'))
    test_indexs1 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_opcodes1)
    test_indexs2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_opcodes2)
    test_indexs1 = pad_sequences(test_indexs1, maxlen=max_opcodes_length)
    test_indexs2 = pad_sequences(test_indexs2, maxlen=max_opcodes_length)
    embedding_matrix_path = 'SJBCD-PAP/something_files/embedding_word2vec_200_matrix.npy'
    embedding_dim = 200
    model_save_path = 'SJBCD-PAP/something_files/sjbcd_word2vec_200.h5'
    embedding_matrix = np.load(embedding_matrix_path, 'r')
    sum_opcodes = len(embedding_matrix)
    model = builde_model(embedding_matrix, sum_opcodes, embedding_dim, max_opcodes_length)
    model.load_weights(model_save_path)
    start_time = time.time()
    y_pred = model.predict([test_indexs1, test_indexs2], batch_size=100)
    yy_pred = np.rint(y_pred)

    test_labels = np.array(test_labels)
    print(classification_report(test_labels, yy_pred, digits=4))
    end_time = time.time()
    print("cost time：" + str(end_time - start_time) + "s")

   
test_file ='SJBCD-PAP/dataset/CompiledBCB_test.csv'
evaluate(test_file)
```

print(yy_pred) is a three-dimensional array
print(test_label) is a list